# Link to File URL by default

Tags: images

Every time I insert an image into my post, the default link is to the image attachment page. How can I change it so it always links to the File address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered a similar question on the .org forums [very recently](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/always-link-to-the-image-file-not-attachment-page).

To sum it up though..

1. Go to **http://example.com/wp-admin/options.php** (replace `example.com` with your website address)
2. Scroll down the page until you see `image_default_link_type`
3. Set that option to either `file`, `post` or to an empty value.

**Empty** = *No link*
**File** = *Links to the file(what you asked for)*
**Post** = *Links to the attachment page(default)*

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: **Note:** You'll need to scroll to the bottom of the page and click save after making the appropriate change.