# Default Image Link Type Setting not Working

Tags: images

I'm trying to set my site so that when I upload an image to a post, by default it links to the attachment.

I tried: in [siteurl]/wp-admin/options.php , setting `image_default_link_type` to `attachment` [as mentioned on this tutorial](https://wpsites.net/wordpress-tips/5-ways-to-change-default-image-links/). I verified that the setting was saved because I set this weeks ago and when I came back to options.php, it was still set to `attachment`. Later I tried setting the value to `post` [as mentioned in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9758/7313).

[image: image default link type set to attachment]

Neither of them seemed to change the behavior. When I drag a new image onto a post, it defaults to `link to` value of `none`.

[image: post editor - default value of link to is none]

- WordPress 5.2.1
- PHP 7.2.19
- Maybe relevant plugins:

  - Jetpack 7.4.1
  - W3 Total Cache 0.9.7.4